# PhantomJS not Working on OS-X Sierra

Tags: phantomjs, macos-sierra, gulp-karma

I recently upgraded the OS from El Capitan to Sierra. Now I can not run the JS unit test suit and it gives the following error in the console.

```
 [exec] INFO [framework.browserify]: bundle built
 [exec] INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.35 server started at http://localhost:9876/
 [exec] INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
 [exec] ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS
 [exec]     
 [exec] INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
 [exec] ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS
 [exec]     
 [exec] INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (2/2).
 [exec] ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS
 [exec]     
 [exec] ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
 [exec] [11:43:19] 'test' errored after 14 s
 [exec] [11:43:19] Error: 1
 [exec]   at formatError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
 [exec]   at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
 [exec]   at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
 [exec]   at Gulp.emit (events.js:182:7)
 [exec]   at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/ssrp/workspace/clickhq-v2/frontend/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
 [exec]   at /Users/ssrp/workspace/clickhq-v2/frontend/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
 [exec]   at finish (/Users/ssrp/workspace/clickhq-v2/frontend/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
 [exec]   at cb (/Users/ssrp/workspace/clickhq-v2/frontend/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
 [exec]   at removeAllListeners (/Users/ssrp/workspace/clickhq-v2/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:218:7)
 [exec]   at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/ssrp/workspace/clickhq-v2/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:229:9)
 [exec]   at Server.g (events.js:273:16)
 [exec]   at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
 [exec]   at Server.emit (events.js:179:7)
 [exec]   at emitCloseNT (net.js:1525:8)
 [exec]   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
 [exec]   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Searched for a solution but could not. Could anybody give me the reason and and a direction to go with. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of phantomjs do you have installed?

Comment: 1.9.8 is installed as of now!

Comment: 1.9.x is not supported anymore. I would guess your problem is related to [PhantomJS 1.9.8 Segmentation fault 11 in macOS Sierra #14558](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14558)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to PhantomJS v2.x solved the problem.

Comment: I had 1.9.0 installed. Sierra broke it with 'segmentation fault 11'.

After upgrading to phantomjs 2.x on the mac os sierra, I continued to get the error. 

I had to also delete an old link for phantom:

`brew link --overwrite phantomjs`

or from the docs before installing/upgrading phantom I could have:

`brew unlink phantomjs@1.90`

Answer (score 1):

My issue wasn't with Phantom js, I had to upgrade  "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^1.0.3".